# Azure throwing "Is Not A Function" error on code that worked locally

Tags: javascript

So, we are working on a project from a previous group. We are to deploy this code to Azure. This code was working just fine locally, but Azure is throwing the error "application.forEach is not a function." Below is the snippet of code that it is freaking out about.

```
function getProjectWeights(applications) {
var weights = {};
console.log(applications);
applications.forEach(function(application)  {
    switch(Number(application.Preference_Order)) {

        case 1: weights[application.Project_ID] = (
            weights[application.Project_ID] || 0
        ) + 1; break;

        case 2: weights[application.Project_ID] = (
            weights[application.Project_ID] || 0
        ) + 1/2; break;

        case 3: weights[application.Project_ID] = (
            weights[application.Project_ID] || 0
        ) + 1/3; break;
    };
});
return weights;
```

};

It is throwing the error for several other functions, but I figured once I get this figured out, the solution could be applied to the rest.

EDIT: I was able to get the Object saved as an Array to get the forEach() function working. This is now throwing an error else where. Here is the code that throwing the fit...

```
]).then(function([query, students, projects, applications, assignments]) {
        element = $("#assignment-table");
        template = "./templates/assignment-table.htm";
        renderTemplate(query, template, element).done(function() {

            var weights = getProjectWeights(applications);
            $.each(weights, function(index, weight) {
                var element = $(`#assignment-td-${index}-weight`);
                element.html((Math.round(weight * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
            });

            if (!assignments.length) {
                var enabled = [
                    $("#assignment-input-min"),
                    $("#assignment-input-max"),
                    $("#assignment-button-minimize"),
                    $("#assignment-button-maximize"),
                    $("#assignment-button-assign"),
                    $("#assignment-button-update"),
                    $("#assignment-button-reset"),
                ]; enableElements(enabled);
```

The error is "Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: what's the result of `console.log(applications);` ... is it an Array or other such object with a `forEach` method?

Comment: This is directly from the console.

Comment: {Application_ID: "1", Student_ID: "2", Project_ID: "1", Preference_Order: "1", Date: "2020-03-17 17:01:14"}
Application_ID: "1"
Student_ID: "2"
Project_ID: "1"
Preference_Order: "1"
Date: "2020-03-17 17:01:14"
__proto__: Object

Comment: so, it's NOT an Array - that's the problem - where you call `getProjectWeights` you need to send an Array

Comment: I see... What would be a better solution to this then?

Comment: I tried making a for loop, but this creates another error elsewhere in the project.

Comment: a better solution is to make sure that the data you use locally is in the same format as the data you use on Azure - no point testing your code locally with an Array, when on Azure you don't use an Array

Comment: The previous group tested it locally. The data is coming from a SQL database server. I'm not sure if that helps any.

Comment: nope - I can't see either the data you test with, or the data you have an issue with ... does the `console.log(applications)` when testing look like a different type of object than it does in Azure?

Comment: It is the same while testing locally, but works as intended.

Comment: are you sure? if it's not an array it will fail

Comment: Positive. It shows as an Object.

Comment: what does `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(applications))` output in each environment?